# Custom input not showing

Tags: arrays, c

There are two test cases with different custom input, what I have to do is print out the custom input and its sum and average using only one code in c language.

I already have a code but its not complete yet. The output prints the correct sum and average, but I also have to print the input (numbers that will be added and get the average from) it was a custom input, there were two test cases with different input (numbers) and I should only use one code for them. My problem is the custom input in not showing up.

Here is the initial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int size, avg, i;
    int sum = 0.0;
    int num_array[6];

    printf("Elements are: %d ",&num_array);

    for (i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
        printf(" ");
        scanf("%d",&num_array[i]);
        sum +=num_array[i];
    }

    printf("\nSum :%d\n",sum);

    avg = sum / 6;
    printf("Average : %d",avg);

    return 0;
}
```

The custom input is not showing up:

```
Elements are:

Sum :24

Average : 4
```

This is expected output:

```
Elements are:  3 7 4 2 6 2

Sum :24

Average : 4
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and fix your warnings

Comment: You may want to print the input values inside the loop as well. Chances are, that it will only appear on the console once the `\n` beneath the loop has been processed.

Comment: One question. What exactly do you expect `printf("Elements are: %d ",&num_array);` to print?

Comment: I expect the custom input to print

Comment: How do you expect it to print all the elements when you haven't initialised the array? And a single ```printf``` wouldn't output all the elements of the array. And what do you think this ```&``` operator does?

Comment: gomen,  How would code `printf("Elements are: %d ",&num_array);`   somehow print the values in the array before there are read in the later loop?

Comment: sorry, I'm still learning so it's a bit confusing

Comment: there are two test cases with different elements, so I'm not sure if I can initialized them or how

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the initial printf statement is not going to list out your input elements.  Actually, it will probably print out a very large integer number denoting the memory address of your integer array similar to the following.

```
Elements are: 1900358384
```

Most likely, there was a compiler warning similar to the following noting this unusual print formatting if warnings were on in the program build.

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[6]’ [-Wformat=]|
```

And as noted the listing of the elements would have to happen after the entry by the user.

With that in mind, following is a revised code snippet which probably produces the output you are desiring.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size, avg, i;
    int sum = 0.0;
    int num_array[6];

    //printf("Elements are: %d ",&num_array);     /* This is going to print the memory address of your array */

    for (i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
        scanf("%d",&num_array[i]);
        sum +=num_array[i];
    }

    printf("Elements are: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)                     /* This is going to print out your inputs */
    {
        printf("%d ", num_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nSum :%d\n",sum);

    avg = sum / 6;
    printf("Average : %d\n",avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some key points.

- The original printf statement is deactivated as the output from it is not what is desired.
- A for loop is added to read through the stored input array elements to print them at the proper location.

Utilizing this refactored code snippet, following is some sample terminal output.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Elements/bin/Release$ ./Elements 
 3
 7
 4
 2
 6
 2
Elements are: 3 7 4 2 6 2 

Sum :24
Average : 4
```

Review the code snippet and see if it meets the spirit of your project.